# C Checking or Converting Exponents

Tags: c++, c, exponent

I have exponents in the represented format of: "1.45e004" or "1.45e-04" or "-1.45e004".

[please note the minus sign in the third one]

Checking (==, !=, >, <, <=, >=, etc) does not work on exponents [incorrect or no results are returned] in their current format.

**However**, converting an exponent using fabs works for the first two, but not the last one, as fabs removes the minus sign (ergo making the value positive and not negative as it should be).

My questions are thus:

**1)** Is there a way to convert exponents into absolutes which would include signed values?

[fabs cannot do this]

OR

**2)** Is there a way [or function(s)] to compare one exponent to another (must be able to do ==, !=, >, <, >=, <=)?

OR

**3)** Is there a way to extract the two values from the exponent.

EG: "-1.45e-04" [Value1 = -1.45, Value2 = -4].

Answers for questions **1** and/or **2** are greatly preferred as 3 is a work around that may have issues with implementation (however, it's there in-case 1 and 2 don't have any suitable answers).

[Side-note: C++ methods can be used, although avoidance of stream is preferred ]

Thank you

```
int main(void)
{
    //Not the actual program, but simple enough
    char Arr[100];
    double T1, T2;

    sprintf(Arr,"-1.45e004");
    T1 = atof(Arr);

    printf("%f\n",fabs(T1)); //Fails to show the minus sign

    return 0;
}
```

The overall goal can be achieved thus having any of the three questions answered:

Either:
1) Direct comparison (using a function) between the two exponents in the given format to see if they are the same, not the same, greater, less than (etc) for sorting of the greatest exponent to the least exponent (not contained in the program as how the sorting is implement is not relevant: only the checking needs to be resolved).

2) Indirect comparison, by converting it into another type that can be directly compared.

3) Direct comparison using an awkward work around by comparing the two numbers in the exponent separately.

[Background details]

The actual program spans 7 header files and 1 cpp, so I cannot display a particular segment given it's intertwined.

It task is thus: files downloaded from the ACE satellite are parsed as arguments, loaded into  memory, converted into their appropriate types. The stored types are then sorted and prepared (current stage) to render a graph (not yet implemented).

At the moment, I am dealing with exponents (stored in the ACE satellite text files in the format given above). These exponents need to be scanned through to find the greatest exponent and the least exponent, so the graph can be correctly spaced between the two. After this, each exponent will be compared to see if it is greater (higher on the graph) or lesser than (lower on the graph) a given set of numbers.

For that task, I need comparisons between exponents. Given I'm inexperienced with them, I decided to ask here.

Comment: "Exponents"? "Absolutes"? "Checking an exponent"? "Converting an exponent"?

Comment: When you use fabs on an exponent stored in a double, it returns the absolute [don't quote me, I am not sure on exponents myself]. So instead of "1.45e004" it would show 14500.0.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, so forgive me if I was being naive.

Comment: Yeah, that's what `fabs` does. Anyway, if you want to get help, I suggest you post some code and clearly explain what exactly in that code isn't working as you expect it to.

Comment: A floating point number is represented according to a standard, not according to this or another string-formatting pattern. Please provide some code, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: I feel that you are being pedantic. I never said that this was how floating point numbers should conform. I said this was how the exponents (in the program) were represented - which thus far are deemed acceptable given fabs can convert it correctly. The exponents are stored in a text file, but I am unsure why I would have to go to the length of explaining this given it has no benefit and I have sufficiently laid out the parameters of the problem.

Comment: It would help if you would describe your overall goal here, rather than asking questions about an implementation that may or may not be appropriate for your purpose. It does seem that you're doing something unusual here, so you're going to have to help us out.

Comment: I have added in some goals. I think I will add some background details.

Comment: @SightS2: I am very confused by your use of the word *exponent*. As far as I am concerned, `-1.45e-04` is a *floating-point number* that is represented by a *significant* (or *mantissa*), in the example `-1.45` and an *exponent*, in the example `-04`. So, when you say you *want to convert/compare the exponents* do you really mean *exponents*, or do you actually mean *the entire numbers*?

Comment: @SightS2: You've created confusion by refering to fabs (an absolute value is essentially the same number without a sign).  It has nothing to do with converting numbers to/from floats.  In the code you've posted, atof is what's converting the the string value into a float (which didn't work for me on ideone), once you have it in floats you can just do the comparisons you're talking about.

Comment: Go read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_number and some articles linked from it, such as "Exponent". You are misusing the terminology, and also seem to be confusing string representation of numbers with numbers themselves. Your question as is makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why your are calling `fabs()` in this line:

```
printf("%f\n",fabs(T1)); //Fails to show the minus sign
```

That's what `fabs()` does, it makes negative numbers positive. Perhaps you want this:

```
printf("%f\n",T1);
```

Comparison of two floating point numbers can be done directly:

```
double x = 12.345e67;
double y = 6.543e-2;
if (x > y) {
    puts("x is greater than y");
}
```

Comment: So there is no issue between comparing two exponents? If this is the case, I am a dummy.

Comment: That's right, floating point number comparisons are built in to C++.

Comment: @Greg: Though, as @unwind mentions in his answer, there are pitfalls when comparing floating-point numbers.

Comment: I knew it was so for floating points (hence my attempt at converting with fabs), but I didn't think it was done with exponents. I am officially a dummy. I will choose this answer then leave ashamed.

Comment: @Space_Cowboy, What kind of pitfalls are those? I need to be wary.

Comment: @SightS2: Read the article @unwind links in his answer. Really, there are no excuses. You have to read it.

Comment: @SightS2:  I think the article might be a little beyond you now, but be sure to read it sometime.  The main pitfall is that floating-point numbers are inexact.  Every time you calculate with them, you're likely to loose a tiny bit of accuracy.  Most of the time, this is unimportant, but, as a general rule, do NOT compare floating-point numbers for equality.  Two mathematically equivalent calculations can wind up, when done on the computer, with slight differences in the output.  Instead of `a == b`, use `fabs(a - b) < 1e-9` (for doubles; change the constant for floats) or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), to at least help you with the vocabulary.

Perhaps you can compute the exponent using:

```
const double exp = log(value) / log(10.0);
```

Your question is hard to understand, it's not well-defined what it means to "check" a floating point number, what it is that you are trying to determine?

**UPDATE:** To compare numbers, just do it. All of your three sample values are just legal floating-point numbers and can be directly compared using the standard build-in operators.

Comment: I am attempting to determine if one floating point number is greater than another. This will be used to determine a max/min (for a graph) and then the position the number would take up on the graph.

Comment: I cannot use log or other functions as the numbers are not generated in-program (the exponents are stored in the format given in the question: they are in a text file, data from the ACE satellite).

Comment: Your information was useful as well, but I don't think I can accept two answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to extract the *coefficient* and *base* parts from a number expressed in scientific notation. There is no standard library function to do this, but you can write one easily:

```
static int
extract_coeff_and_base (double d, char *coeff, char *base)
{
  char buffer[50];
  size_t i;
  size_t len;

  sprintf (buffer, "%E\n", d);
  len = strlen (buffer);
  i = strcspn (buffer, "E");
  if (i < len)
    {
      memcpy (coeff, buffer, i);
      coeff[i] = 0;
      memcpy (base, buffer + i + 1, len - i);
      base[len - i] = 0;
      return 0;
    }
  return 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  double d = atof (argv[1]);
  char coeff[20];
  char base[20];

  if (extract_coeff_and_base (d, coeff, base) == 0)
    {
      printf ("coefficient=%s, base=%s\n", coeff, base);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Tests:

```
$ ./test.exe 1.45e004
coefficient=1.450000, base=+04

$ ./test.exe 1.45e-04
coefficient=1.450000, base=-04

$ ./test.exe -1.45e004
coefficient=-1.450000, base=+04
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find what you're looking for in this example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const char *nums[] = {"1.45e004", "1.45e-04", "-1.45e004", NULL};

int main() {
  const char **numstring = nums;
  while (*numstring != NULL) {
    double num = strtod(*numstring, NULL);
    double sign = copysign(1.0, num);
    double exponent = trunc(log10(sign * num));
    double mantissa = num / pow(10, exponent);
    printf("%s -> %g, mantissa=%f, exponent=%f\n", *numstring, num, mantissa, exponent);
    numstring++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```